# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ERROR' for .predict in GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, predict

The .predict function for a GradientBoostingRegressor model gives a traceback error is this because my new input data is an ndarray object?

I have built a GradientBoostingRegressor model using scikit-learn. Now I want to use the model to predict values for new input data.

```
title = "Learning Curves (Gradient Boosted Regression Trees)" 
estimator = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=best_est.n_estimators, 
                                      max_depth=best_est.max_depth, 
                                      learning_rate=best_est.learning_rate, 
                                   min_samples_leaf=best_est.min_samples_leaf, 
                                      max_features=best_est.max_features,
                                      alpha=best_est.alpha
                                      ) 
newdataraw = pd.read_csv('X_predict.csv')
newdata = newdataraw

#Remove columns that are not part of X
cols = ['Year', 'AFFGEOID','Utilities','STATEFP','COUNTYFP']
for i in cols:
    del newdata[i]
X_predict = newdata.values
X_predict = np.nan_to_num(X_predict)
predictX = estimator.predict(X_predict)
```

### Traceback error:

File "", line 1, in 
    predictX = estimator.predict(X_predict)

File "C:\Users...\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py", line 2530, in predict
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, order="C", accept_sparse='csr')

File "C:\Users...\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)

File "C:\Users...\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

### ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ERROR'

X_predict is displaying in the variable explorer as Type Object and Value "ndarray object of numpy module"

Comment: it looks like `X_predict`, which is coming from `pd.read_csv()` has some strings in it, can you post the preprocessing you did on your training data

Comment: There isnt any strings in X_predict. the error comes from somewhere in the .predict function with "check_array" which has the following note: "By default, the input is checked to be a non-empty 2D array containing only finite values. If the *dtype of the array is object*, attempt converting to float, raising on failure" in the failed exceptions it turns the values to "ERROR" which is the raised string flag. This is why I ask if the issue is because X_predict is an ndarray object and not a float64 --  how do I fix it?

Comment: When you read a file in with `pd.read_csv()` it might not be converting all of your data to `ints`. try printing `newdata.dtypes`

Comment: Yes I had tried that all the dtypes are float64 - any more checks I can do?

Comment: I managed to get around the issue by editing the csv to remove the headers and loading it directly as a numpy array using numpy.genfromtxt('filename.csv',delimiter=',') I would still be curious as to how to resolve the code above so that the X_predict loads as an array and not an object.